# How can I improve the specification table on the back page of this brochure design?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, critique, design-principles

I'm working on a brochure for this Garmin device and would appreciate some feedback! In particular, how I could improve the Specification table on the back page and any design tweaks you think are necessary. Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE! We typically require of critique questions to be fairly specific so I edited your title accordingly. Is there something about your table that you feel is off and needs improvement?

Comment: For one thing, top-align the text in the cells. And _use the correct multiplication character_. The letter x does not mean ‘by’ – you want × for that.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What do you think is wrong with the table, or why do you think it needs to be improved?

Comment: So... so.. so much could be done. Stop looking at it as a "table" but rather 10 item headers and minor subtext... so display 10 things on page.. do that... forget the "table" structure completely. -- 2 rows of 5 items.. 5 rows of 2 items... 3 rows of 3 items then a callout item.... so .. so.. so much can be done it's impossible to answer. You've merely locked yourself into seeing it as a table structure....

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague, but I'll give it a go!

Generally I think all the elements are too evenly spaced out. You can create a more harmonious layout by moving similar elements closer and create more space between groups of objects.

Here is a quick manipulation of your layout made in Photoshop. Don't pay too much attention to the details.

[image]

### Front

- The margins seem too narrow, I made them wider.
- The lines between the list items are not needed to differentiate between them. I removed them.
- The list items are too far away from each other to seem like a group. I moved them closer.
- It's a problem that the background image has so many details right behind the product. Almost looks like small antennas sticking out. I've evened out the background and move the product up a bit. It's a bit empty so it needs more work, but I think it's better to be able to see the product without clutter. Could be done in other ways.

### Back

- The margins seem too narrow, I made them wider.
- The header haven't got enough space around it. I moved it down and increased the space to the table below.
- The rows with multiple lines look messy. I top-aligned the text in the cells.
- There is too much space between the table rows. It makes the table fall apart. I decreased the space between rows.